# How to read and write very large files into sqlite - blob columns in PHP?

Tags: php, sqlite

I want to insert an (arbitrarily large) uploaded file into an sqlite3-database in PHP.

Normally I would use `file_get_contents()` and then put the string into an SQL-command, but then I run into the 128MB memory limit.

According to [this discussion thread](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/64152), there seems to be also no easy command-line solution. (But of course I would be happy to hear otherwise.)

How can I read/write a single BLOB-field without running out of memory?

Comment: Usually, you store large files on their own, rather than in a database. If you must store it in the database, try reading and writing the file in chunks, so that the server only has to store one chunk of of the file in memory at a time (I don't know if PHP supports doing that though).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since sqlite 3.8.6, the readfile/writefile commands are available:

http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#fileio

Read a file:

```
CREATE TABLE images(name TEXT, type TEXT, img BLOB);
INSERT INTO images(name,type,img) VALUES('icon','jpeg',readfile('icon.jpg'));
```

Write a file:

```
SELECT writefile('icon.jpg',img) FROM images WHERE name='icon';
```

Comment: In case you've got a text file, you can do `CAST(readfile(...) AS TEXT)` to avoid it being treated as a `BLOB`.